# after moving to new angular http success not working

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

Hy,

I moved to new angular and http success stops working. I replaced to "then" function and on one hand it seems like it works as angular but on the other hand hoping result doesnt seem to work and no outputs there. In other words, there are just empty places where the ouput should be.

one of examples where still doesnt work after moving to new angular:

```
$http.post("/BUS/dropboxInicialisation/", {}).then(function(result) {
   $scope.available_dates = result;
});
```

Comment: as i know (but sure at 70%) success is deprecated .. then and catch are better

Comment: with `.success` use `result.data` with `.then` use `result`

Comment: It'll help if you shared your code.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi As I said, there is no output with "then".

Comment: @Merlin not working

Comment: Does your `post` method return anything at all? Also what is `new angular` can you be more precise.

Comment: @Jax sorry, your suggestion still doesnt work, but I still try do change by change. By saying "new angular" I ment "version of new angular"

Comment: try to put also a catch .. maybe it's going inerror ..something liek this:   $http.post("/BUS/dropboxInicialisation/", {})
     .then(function (result) {

         $scope.available_dates = result;


     }).catch(function(err){ console.log(err); });

Comment: thank you all guys for help for a while. Solution solved by changing "result" to "result.data" and doing the suggestion

Comment: hy again, can anyone tell me why my MVC (with angular) app works on IIS 5577 port, but on 80 dont? now it works little better after changing localhost to 127... but the post dont work. In VS it works, but on IIS 80 port not.